# Access to apc.php in Drupal

Tags: drupal, apc

I have configured a server with Digital Ocean and installed APC. It works fine, but when I tried to access to apc.php in order to see stats, I get an HTTP Auth dialog asking me for introducing user and password. The apc.php file is located at /sites/all/libraries/apc_admin/{privatekey}/apc.php

I have tried moving the file to /var/www and it works fine.

Anybody knows what is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this might be sound obvious, but have you checked for a .htaccess file in the folder structure that has an Auth entry in it? The entry will look something like the following:

```
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Secret Folder"
Require valid-user
```